# TextField Label to show separately from input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Currently using this code of `material-ui`, the label is showing on the top-left corner of input, but what if I wanted to show the label outside of input separately. I know I can do this using the `<InputLabel/>` but is there any alternative that can done using `<TextField/>` only.

```
     <TextField
            id="username"
            label={<Typography className={classes.label}>Username</Typography>}
            fullWidth
            margin="normal"
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
            InputProps={{
              classes: { input: classes.inputs },
            }}
            name="username"
            autoComplete="username"
            autoFocus
            helperText={touched.username ? errors.username : ''}
            error={touched.username && Boolean(errors.username)}
            value={values.username}
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
```

Comment: @gukiran-singh "Label outside of input means" without the outline ?

Comment: @Subhanshu No actually, it means like in bootstrap the label totally separate from input.  I am sorry, if I didn't make it much clearer. [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls)

Answer (score 0):

I used a [Grid](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/) and [InputLabel](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input-label/) to be able to make what you want by manually implementing the label and define its position, I have something like this:

```
<Grid container >
    <Grid item xs={12}>
        <InputLabel
            shrink={false}
            htmlFor={"username"}
        >
            <Typography className={classes.label}>Username</Typography>
        </InputLabel>

     <TextField
            id="username"
            fullWidth
            margin="normal"
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
            InputProps={{
              classes: { input: classes.inputs },
            }}
            name="username"
            autoComplete="username"
            autoFocus
            helperText={touched.username ? errors.username : ''}
            error={touched.username && Boolean(errors.username)}
            value={values.username}
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```